# ASP.NET MVC 3 Model has no information on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view with a couple of partial views that I bind to my model. For some reason, when I post, the model is empty, and I am not sure why.

Below is my ViewModel.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public bool AdvancedSearchOption { get; set; }
    public bool ForceAdvanced { get; set; }
    public bool ForceSimple { get; set; }
    public string SimpleSearchCriteria { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumberCriteria { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumberCriteria { get; set; }
    public string NameCriteria { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumberCriteria { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller. I am filling in all the values of the viewmodel because I wanted to see if the values got to the partial views. They do get there, so it is just on the post that I am having issues.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ISecurityRepository SecurityRep;

    public HomeController(ISecurityRepository repo)
    {
        SecurityRep = repo;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IndexViewModel temp = new IndexViewModel();
        temp.AdvancedSearchOption = SecurityRep.DefaultToAdvancedSearch(User.Identity.Name);
        temp.ForceAdvanced = false;
        temp.ForceSimple = false;
        temp.SimpleSearchCriteria = "Testing";
        temp.AccountNumberCriteria = "Acct";
        temp.CustomerNumberCriteria = "Cust";
        temp.NameCriteria = "Name";
        temp.PhoneNumberCriteria = "Phone";
        return View(temp);
    }

    public ActionResult SimpleSearch()
    {
        IndexViewModel temp = new IndexViewModel();
        temp.AdvancedSearchOption = SecurityRep.DefaultToAdvancedSearch(User.Identity.Name);
        temp.ForceAdvanced = false;
        temp.ForceSimple = true;
        temp.SimpleSearchCriteria = "Testing";
        temp.AccountNumberCriteria = "Acct";
        temp.CustomerNumberCriteria = "Cust";
        temp.NameCriteria = "Name";
        temp.PhoneNumberCriteria = "Phone";
        return View("Index",temp);
    }

    public ActionResult AdvancedSearch()
    {
        IndexViewModel temp = new IndexViewModel();
        temp.AdvancedSearchOption = SecurityRep.DefaultToAdvancedSearch(User.Identity.Name);
        temp.ForceAdvanced = true;
        temp.ForceSimple = false;
        temp.SimpleSearchCriteria = "Testing";
        temp.AccountNumberCriteria= "Acct";
        temp.CustomerNumberCriteria= "Cust";
        temp.NameCriteria= "Name";
        temp.PhoneNumberCriteria = "Phone";
        return View("Index", temp);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel vm, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is my view

```
@model TRIOSoftware.Magnum.Models.IndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

@if ((@Model.AdvancedSearchOption && @Model.ForceSimple != true) || @Model.ForceAdvanced == true)
{
    @Html.Partial("AdvancedSearch")
}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("SimpleSearch")
}
```

Here is my `SimpleSearch` partial view. I think if I can get this one working, the other will follow the same path. I do the post in the partial and I use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) to do it. I am not sure if either of these things could cause me issues or not. I only have all the hidden items in there because I didn't know if not having them was causing my issues.

```
 @model TRIOSoftware.Magnum.Models.IndexViewModel

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#DefaultDiv").find("#DefaultAdvanced").click(function () {
             $.post("DefaultSimple");
         });

         $("#SearchSection").find("#SearchButton").click(function () {
             $.post("");
         });
     });
</script>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home"))
 {
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ForceAdvanced)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AdvancedSearchOption)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ForceSimple)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccountNumberCriteria)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerNumberCriteria)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NameCriteria)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PhoneNumberCriteria)

     <div id="DefaultDiv" style="float:right">
         <a id="DefaultAdvanced" href="#" class="ButtonClass">Default Simple Search</a>
     </div>

     <div style="clear:both; margin: auto; width: 800px">
         <img src="../../Content/images/TRIO_transparent_image.gif"; alt="TRIO Software"; style="margin-left:150px; clear:left"/>
             <div style="clear:left; float: left" class="SearchText">
                  @Html.Label("What's your inquiry?:")
                  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SimpleSearchCriteria, new { style = "width: 400px" })
             </div>
             <div id="SearchSection" style="float: left" class="SearchText">
                 <a href="#"; id="SearchButton" class="ButtonClass"><img src="../../Content/images/Search.gif"; alt="Search"; style="float:left" /></a>
             </div>
             <p style="clear:left;margin-left:400px">
                 @Html.ActionLink("Advanced Search", "AdvancedSearch", null, new { style = "clear:left" })
             </p>

    </div>
 }
```

Here is the HTML code when viewing the simple search partial view:

```
<div id="main">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#DefaultDiv").find("#DefaultAdvanced").click(function () {
                $.post("DefaultSimple");
            });

            $("#SearchSection").find("#SearchButton").click(function () {
                $.post("");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <form method="post" action="/">
        <input type="hidden" value="False" name="ForceAdvanced" id="ForceAdvanced" data-val-required="The ForceAdvanced field is required." data-val="true">
        <input type="hidden" value="False" name="AdvancedSearchOption" id="AdvancedSearchOption" data-val-required="The AdvancedSearchOption field is required." data-val="true">
        <input type="hidden" value="False" name="ForceSimple" id="ForceSimple" data-val-required="The ForceSimple field is required." data-val="true">
        <input type="hidden" value="Acct" name="AccountNumberCriteria" id="AccountNumberCriteria">
        <input type="hidden" value="Cust" name="CustomerNumberCriteria" id="CustomerNumberCriteria">
        <input type="hidden" value="Name" name="NameCriteria" id="NameCriteria">
        <input type="hidden" value="Phone" name="PhoneNumberCriteria" id="PhoneNumberCriteria">
        <div style="float:right" id="DefaultDiv">
            <a class="ButtonClass ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" href="#" id="DefaultAdvanced" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text">Default Simple Search</span></a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both; margin: auto; width: 800px">
            <img style="margin-left:150px; clear:left" alt="TRIO Software" ;="" src="../../Content/images/TRIO_transparent_image.gif">
            <div class="SearchText" style="clear:left; float: left">
               <label for="What_s_your_inquiry_:">What's your inquiry?:</label>
               <input type="text" value="Testing" name="SimpleSearchCriteria" id="SimpleSearchCriteria" class="text-box single-line">
            </div>
            <div class="SearchText" style="float: left" id="SearchSection">
                <a class="ButtonClass ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="SearchButton" ;="" href="#" role="button"><span class="ui-button-text"><img style="float:left" alt="Search" ;="" src="../../Content/images/Search.gif"></span></a>
            </div>
            <p style="clear:left;margin-left:400px">
                <a style="clear:left" href="/Home/AdvancedSearch">Advanced Search</a>
            </p>
     </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried explicitly sending in the model to the partials with no luck. I believe that the partial views get the parent model by default if nothing is specified, so all I needed to do was to specify the model type in my partials, and I got the information.

I finally figured it out with a lot of trial and error. My issue was being caused by me trying to use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) to do a post. There must be some other things you need to do to update your model doing it this way. Once I changed it out and put an input control on the form for the post, I got all my data back from the parent and partial view in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Although you're selecting a partial to render, you're not passing it the model.  There's an overloaded version of `Html.Partial` that takes a second argument that allows you to pass a model to it:

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName", Model);
```

So in your case, you'd use this:

```
@if ((Model.AdvancedSearchOption && Model.ForceSimple != true) || Model.ForceAdvanced == true) 
{ 
    @Html.Partial("AdvancedSearch", Model)  
} 
else 
{ 
    @Html.Partial("SimpleSearch", Model)  
}
```

Also notice how I've removed the `@`s you were prefixing `Model` with.  To better understand why, please see [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax) and a small reference for this same topic written by Phil Haack [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think @john-h hit the nail on the head with his answer. However, you might want to reduce the complexity you've created for yourself.

1) Since both ForceSimple and ForceAdvanced are Boolean, it would be assumed that when ForceAdvanced is true, then it's not "Simple", right? I'm not sure what other logic you have here.

2) Rather than creating two views and "posting" back to get the correct one, why not just use a parameter to set the search type? Or evaluate the security to set which one the user can execute. Here's an example:

Controller Actions:

```
//id is the search type: true is Advanced
public ActionResult Search(bool id) {
    IndexViewModel viewModel = new IndexViewModel {
        /* Do whatever logic here  */
        ForceAdvanced = (id) ? false : true,
        AdvancedSearchOption = id
    };
    return View("search", viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(IndexViewModel model) {
    //model.SimpleSearchCriteria = "Testing";
    //model.PhoneNumberCriteria = "Phone";
    return View("search", model);
}
```

Search View:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm(new { id = @Model.AdvancedSearchOption })) {
    <div style="clear:left; float: left" class="SearchText">
        @Html.Label("What's your inquiry?:")
        @if (Model.AdvancedSearchOption) {
            <div>
                @* if you really want, load your partial views here *@
                <span>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NameCriteria)</span>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NameCriteria, new { style = "width: 400px" })
                <span>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumberCriteria)</span>
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PhoneNumberCriteria, new { style = "width: 400px" })
            </div>
        }
        else {
             @* if you really want, load your partial views here *@
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SimpleSearchCriteria, new { style = "width: 400px" })
        }        
    </div>
    <div>
         <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>   
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ForceAdvanced)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AdvancedSearchOption)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ForceSimple)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccountNumberCriteria)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerNumberCriteria)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NameCriteria)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PhoneNumberCriteria)    
}
```